# Upstart is not finding my job

Tags: upstart

Hi there I have made the following job:

```
description     "Emacs daemon"

start on runlevel[2345]
stop on runlevel[!2345]

expect daemon
respawn
respawn limit 10 5 # respawn up to 10 times, waiting 5 seconds each time

pre-start script
        echo "Starting emacs daemon..." > /home/kabelo/Desktop/emacs.log
end script

pre-stop script
    emacsclient -n -e '(save-persistent-scratch)'
end script

exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid kabelo --exec /usr/bin/emacs -- --daemon -u kabelo
```

when I placd in in `~/.config/upstart` then the commands `sudo start emacs`, `start emacs`, print the error, `start: Unknown job: emacs.` The same error is printed when I put it in both `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`, in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions`, in `~/.init`. Now I'm too fed up to try making a directory, calling it `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and putting it there, since I'm pretty certain it would work. Why isn't the script working no matter where I put it. Note that I want it as a "Session  Job" so that I can start it without sudo as documented in the docs.

Comment: What is the output of env?

Answer (score 2):

You should store your script in the `/etc/init` directory, you may also want to run `init-checkconfig emacs.conf` on your script and `initctl check-config`.

Comment: Okay, so I moved it to `/etc/init` however, when I start it using `sudo start emacs` no processes named `emacs` appears when I list all processes.

Comment: Ask another question. I only knew how to make the upstart job start, doing a script ending in `.conf` in the `/etc/init` directory. I'm not user of emacs tho